# CSS3 webkit blur ghosting issue

Tags: css, webkit

I have a UI where the navigation is over a blurred set of images (blurred using webkit blur), and whenever the navigation moves, theres this strange almost ghosting effect that happens. After you click away onto another element, the ghosting also goes away.

Any advice on how to solve this?

On Mac Snow Leopard:

- Chrome 19.0.1084.56
- Safari all of them, including 6 beta

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo? Which browser/version are you using? (Google Chrome? Safari?)

Comment: I had the same issue, here is a jsfiddle that causes the ghosting: http://jsfiddle.net/MJ95B/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are encountering a browser/engine dependent issue.
Chances are : you can't solve it by yourself aside from not using blur, or the like.

Not that this bug might not impact all users, depending on the version of the webkit they are using.

Hopefully the problem will be corrected in a future version. Maybe try to contact webkit guys, but that's really all you can do (aside submitting a patch).